# Lua Iterators: Interchanging argument's position results in infinite loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua, lua-table

If i am interchanging the argument position in `function iter2(max,key)` to `iter2(key,max)` and invoking the same as `iter,1,8` it is resulting in an infinite loop.

```
function iter2(max,key)
   if key == nil then
      return 2 , "value:" .. 2
   end
   if key >= max then
      return nil
   else 
      return key+2, "value:" .. key+2
   end

end

for k,v in iter2,8,1 do
   print(k,v)
end
```

What is the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Lua PiL chapter](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.2.html) on the behaviour of `for`-statement:

> ```
> for <var-list> in <exp-list> do
>   <body>
> end
> ```
>
> The first thing the `for` does is to evaluate the expressions after
>   the in. These expressions should result in the three values kept by
>   the `for`: the *iterator function*, the *invariant state*, and the
>   *initial value* for the *control variable*. [...]
>
> After this initialization step, the `for` calls the iterator function
>   with two arguments: the invariant state and the control variable.
>   (Notice that, for the `for` structure, the invariant state has no
>   meaning at all. It only gets this value from the initialization step
>   and passes it when it calls the iterator function.) Then the `for`
>   assigns the values returned by the iterator function to variables
>   declared by its variable list. If the first value returned (the one
>   assigned to the control variable) is `nil`, the loop terminates.
>   Otherwise, the `for` executes its body and calls the iteration
>   function again, repeating the process.

Therefore, when you're switching the variables in your definition of the function, you are actually using the value of your **control variable** as **the invariant state**.